# Fetch data from Term Store Management in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: development, navigation, term-store

So I am wanting 3 different navigations and I only see how to add 2 though in the snippet area in Design Manager.

I am comfortable with C# but not very knowledgable in Sharepoint. Does anyone know how to grab a specific term set by reference ID?

Answer (score 1):

First you [create a TaxonomySession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee587369.aspx) for the current site:

```
var TSession = new TaxonomySession(SPContext.Current.Site);
```

Then you can use the [TermStores Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termstorecollection.aspx) to look up your term store using its GUID:

```
var Termstore = TSession.TermStores[termStoreID];
```

You can also do the lookup based on the term store name if that is easier to use.

Comment: Ok. So once I have the object and create the variable, how would I display it. For example in this case I have an id of 123456 that will go and get the navigation based on that it. What command should I use to have Sharepoint display it just like any other navigation?